# Postgres Alter ID Start With?

Tags: sql, postgresql, key, alter

I have an PostgreSQL SQL for creating table. Sometimes i need to TRUNCATE this table. but after this ID primary key, don't start with initial or desired starting value. my question is that how can i restart primary key (id) to desired starting value.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "binance_rules" (
  "id" int8 GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 100100100000),
  "THPARS_DATI" timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  "THPARS_LIST" varchar(10) check ("THPARS_LIST" in ('yes','no')) DEFAULT NULL,
  "THPARS_PRIO" INT DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

any sql example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the table column to restart the counting:

```
alter table binance_rules alter column id restart;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4c394add803892c2a575c663af600c1c) is a db<>fiddle.